# Upside down, paragraph style footnotes

Tags: footnotes, rotating

I am trying to figure out how to typeset solutions to in-text exercises as an upside down, paragraph style footnote, as in the [following image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cpbsk1u4zkzynva/example.png):

[image]

I can easily typeset the solutions in a rightside up paragraph style footnote using `footmisc` with the `para` option. I can also use a `\rotatebox` to typeset the footnotes upside down and one-per-line (albeit, in the reverse order from what I want). However, I can't figure out how to get paragraph style footnotes in which the entire footnote is rotated.

I'd like to be able to produce something that looks like the above using code such as:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\problem}[2]{...}{...}
\begin{document}
\problem{What is 1+1}{two}
\problem{What is 1+2}{three}
\problem{What is 1+3}{four}
\problem{What is 1+4}{five}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I would be happy to produce a MWE, but I am not sure what a MWE that isn't also an answer to my question would look like.

Comment: Even an MWE with what you have tried so far would be useful. It doesn't necessarily have to be 'working' in the sense that it achieves what you're trying to do; it should just be 'working' in the sense that it gives people a place to start with helping you. So even the code that produces the image you've uploaded would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NEW VERSION to respond to revised OP requirements.  EDITED to use a `\protected@edef` as part of `\problem` to facilitate the use of braces `\{...\}` in the footnotes.

It uses the syntax `\problem[]{question}{answer}`.  At this stage, the user must invoke the footnotes in one of two ways:

1. `\showpageanswers` following the final `\problem` on any given page; or
2. provide anything (other than `\relax`) as an optional argument to the last `\problem`  on any given page.

I tried to automate this on a page-by-page basis, but was unsuccessful.

The problem counter will carry over page to page.

I modified `\showpageanswers` so than its invocation without any answers to show will be ignored.

To get the footnote to be able to extend past a single line in length (i.e., paragraph style), I put it in a `\parbox`.  I also kerned -18pt before the rotated `\parbox`, to account for the footnote indent, and added a `\strut` to end of inverted footnote definition (`\revfootnote`), for subsequent vertical spacing.

Note however, if multiple answer sets appear on the same page, saving all the answers for one single footnote invocation per page will prevent the "appearance of" misordered footnotes (since turning them upside down changes the sense of first and last).

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}\newsavebox\fnbox
\def\pageanswers{}
\newcounter{problemNo}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\problem[3][\relax]{%
  \stepcounter{problemNo}%
  \par\smallskip%
  \theproblemNo.~~#2?%
  \par\smallskip%
  \protected@edef\pageanswers{\pageanswers$^{\theproblemNo}$#3\ \quad}%
  \ifx\relax#1\else\showpageanswers\fi%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\showpageanswers{\if\relax\pageanswers\relax\else%
  \revfootnote{\pageanswers}\def\pageanswers{}\fi}
\newcommand\revfootnote[1]{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{}%
  \footnotetext{\savebox\fnbox{\parbox{%
  \dimexpr\textwidth\relax}{#1\strut}}\kern-18pt%
  \rotatebox{180}{\usebox{\fnbox}}}}
\begin{document}
Solve these problems.
\problem{What is 1+1}{two $\{abc\}$}
\problem{What is 1+2}{three}
\problem{What is 1+3}{four}
\problem{What is 1+4}{five}
\problem{What is 1+5}{six}
\problem{What is 1+6}{seven}
\problem{What is 1+7}{eight}
\problem{What is 1+8}{nine}
\lipsum[1]
\problem{What is 2+1}{three}
\problem{What is 2+2}{four}
\problem{What is 2+3}{five}
\problem[x]{What is 2+4}{six}

\lipsum[2-4]
Solve these problems.
\problem{What is 1+1}{two}
\problem{What is 1+2}{three}
\problem{What is 1+3}{four}
\problem{What is 1+4}{five}
\problem{What is 1+5}{six}
\problem{What is 1+6}{seven}
\problem{What is 1+7}{eight}
\problem[x]{What is 1+8}{nine}
\lipsum[5-8]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Darthvader would say: Most impressive ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  "We meet again at last.  The circle is now complete... Join me, and together we can rule the galaxy."

Comment: Give in to your anger ;-)

Comment: I think I shot myself in the foot by providing an MWE that shows how I mimicked the effect that I want for illustrative purposes, as it ended up soliciting other attempts to mimic the effect. To be clear, I am looking for something that typesets footnotes as in footmisc with the [para] option, but rotates the entire footnote box. For example, if a problem overflows onto the next page, its solution should automatically follow it.

Comment: @henry Please look at my revised solution, to see if this better meets your needs.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: This is precisely what I was looking for, modulo the part about invoking \showpageanswers. If you think you might come up with a way to automate this, I'll wait for it; otherwise, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @henry  I will have a try.  Two trial attempts have failed, but I have a third idea.

Comment: @henry  I am sorry, but all my attempts at automation failed.  Trying to key the invocation of `\showpageanswers` to the end of page, I found, was too late in the process to get the footnotes to appear on that page (though I could get them to automatically appear on the following page :^).  I have provided a 2nd means (optional argument to `\problem`) to signify the last problem on a page, though it is still manual.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Now that I am trying to use your macros, I am running into some issues that I don't know how to solve. Specifically, if there is a set ($\{...\}$) in the solution, then I get "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]". I can fix this for a single solution using \noexpand, but then an error gets thrown if I try to include a second problem on the same page.

Comment: @henry surround the definition of `\problem` in a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` and change the `\edef\pageanswers{}` to `\protected@edef\pageanswers{}`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Wonderful! That did the trick! Thank you, sir! One of these days I'll need to figure out expansion...

Answer (score 5):

The `\hfill` is of no use here, but a `\raggedleft` will shift the rotated box to the right margin`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
What is
\begin{enumerate}
\item   1+1?
\item   1+2?
\item   1+3?
\item   1+4?
\end{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{}
\footnotetext{\raggedleft\rotatebox{180}{$^1$ two\qquad $^2$ three\qquad $^3$ four\qquad $^4$ five\hfill}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: looks nice, but it's cheating.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Better cheated than nothing ;-) But the OP changed the question somehow, so my 'solution' is none actually :-(

Comment: hmmm.  weak excuse.  the original question, if read closely, *did* imply that he wanted to be able to generate the footnotes *as paragraphed footnotes* and then rotate the whole box.  (i think your code may be what the op used to get the original visual.  it's a tricky problem!)  see henry's comment following the answer by steven segletes.