# Upside down footnotes

Tags: numbering, footnotes, rotating

I want footnotes to appear upside down. Except for that, they should act as regular footnote, i.e. also share the numbering with non-upside down footnotes. I already found a way of making the footnote appear upside down taken from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229138/upside-down-paragraph-style-footnotes) question, but what is missing is the numbering which I can't quite figure out. Here is a MWE for what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}\newsavebox\fnbox
\newcommand\revfootnote[1]{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{}%
  \footnotetext{\savebox\fnbox{\parbox{%
  \dimexpr\textwidth\relax}{#1\strut}}\kern-18pt%
  \rotatebox{180}{\usebox{\fnbox}}}}
\begin{document}
This sentence has a footnote.\revfootnote{This is the footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you! I'm honestly surprised that it seems so difficult to do this in LaTeX and that there is no 'default' way of doing it. If someone could help I would appreciate it a lot. I think it should be possible to simply alter the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229138/upside-down-paragraph-style-footnotes?noredirect=1&lq=1) a little to get what I'm looking for. But I'm not that familiar with coding in LaTeX so I couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

you can do so with a counter, and slightly modifying your code like this :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlefoot}

\newcounter{revcounter}
\setcounter{revcounter}{1}
\usepackage{enumitem}\newsavebox\fnbox
\newcommand\revfootnote[1]{
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\therevcounter}
  \footnote{\savebox\fnbox{\parbox{%
  \dimexpr\textwidth\relax}{#1\strut}}\kern-18pt%
  \rotatebox{180}{\usebox{\fnbox}}}
  \addtocounter{revcounter}{1}}
\begin{document}
This sentence has a footnote.\revfootnote{This is the footnote.}
\end{document}
```

However, this probably don't work with hyperref package, and it creates a little space between the text and the number, but I don't know why..

Comment: Hey, yea that's better than what I have, but the space doesn't look good and also the number of the footnote at the bottom of the page should appear upside down in front of the footnote as well, as can be seen in [the example I mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229138/upside-down-paragraph-style-footnotes).